# Azure Availability sets and CMS instances

Tags: iis, load-balancing, azure, cms

We are hosting a CMS Site on Azure through a VM and IIS. To keep inline with Microsoft's SLA's we have to put the Front Ends in an availability set and then Load Balance them though an endpoint.

This CMS says not to load balancing the Authoring site because of caching and publishing issues.

Our plan is to load balance the front end on port 443, https://www.myCMSsite.com for FE01 and FE02 and then setup a redirect for https://authoring.myCMSsite.com to  authoring.myCMSsite.com:4433 on FE01.

We understand we will not be meeting Microsoft's SLA on the authoring site.

Is there a better solution to this problem possibly?

Answer (score 1):

I've had to follow a similar approach for Umbraco in the past and have tended to allow authoring to run from one node only with a manual failover in the event that one host goes down.

Depending on your needs you could split your front-end and authoring into three separate cloud services (using 4 hosts instead of 2) which would allow you to have SSL on standard ports for both front-end and authoring.  You would have:

1. Cloud Service 1: Front-end servers (x2) with Azure Load Balancing.
2. Cloud Service 2: Primary Authoring Server (x1) with no Azure Load Balancing.
3. Cloud Service 3: Secondary Authoring Server (x2) with no Azure Load Balancing.

While you can't load balance your authoring hosts with standard you could use [Azure Traffic Manager](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/) with a [failover configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/azure/hh744832.aspx) to manage automatic failover in the event that your primary authoring host goes down.